# kubectl escape special chars

Tags: kubernetes, escaping, zsh, kubectl

I'm trying to set oidc credentials and got stuck, because the client-secret contains a comma:

```
kubectl config set-credentials user@cluster  \
    --auth-provider=oidc  \
    --auth-provider-arg='idp-issuer-url=https://host'  \
    --auth-provider-arg='client-id=xxx'  \
    --auth-provider-arg='client-secret=AAAA,BBBB'
```

This results in the following error:

```
error: Error: invalid auth-provider-arg format: BBBB
```

Is there a way to escape the char?

Answer (score 2):

Mentioning the special characters in a single quote is an exact work around for [escaping special characters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#use-case-pods-with-prod-test-credentials) but in this case as comma is present it's considered as [extra-scope](https://github.com/int128/kubelogin/blob/master/docs/standalone-mode.md#extra-scopes) (Scopes to request to the provider (comma separated)).

Currently kubectl does not accept multiple scopes, so you need to edit the kubeconfig as following:

```
$ kubectl config set-credentials keycloak --auth-provider-arg extra-scopes=SCOPES
sed -i ' ' -e s/SCOPES/email,profile/ $KUBECONFIG
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl config set-credentials user@cluster  \
    --auth-provider=oidc  \
    --auth-provider-arg='idp-issuer-url=https://host'  \
    --auth-provider-arg='client-id=xxx'  \
    --auth-provider-arg='"client-secret=AAAA,BBBB"'
```

Comment: Please include brief description and reference to your answer.